# Extract part of code from an async/await block into a separate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I have an async anonymous self-invoking function. The word “async” before the function means the function will always returns a promise. If the code has return  in it, then JavaScript automatically wraps it into a resolved promise with that value.

This async allows us to use "wait". The keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result. So the function execution “pauses” and resumes when the promise settles. That doesn’t cost any CPU resources, because the engine can do other jobs meanwhile: execute other scripts, handle events etc.

```
(async () => {
    await page.goto('test.com', { waituntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'] });
    await page.evaluate((user, pass) => {
      document.querySelector('#user').setAttribute('value', user);
    }, user, pass)
    await page.click('button[type=submit].btn-primary');


    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        try { 
            await page.goto('test.com/second', { waituntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'] });
        } catch(e) {
                await page.goto('test.com', { waituntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'] });
                await page.evaluate((user, pass) => {
                    document.querySelector('#user').setAttribute('value', user);
                }, user, pass)
                await page.click('button[type=submit].btn-primary');
        } 

        // more stuff not relevant here
    }    

})();
```

But as you can see above, I have duplicate code. I want to extract the duplicate code into a separate function. Something like this:

```
(async () => {

    logIn()

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        try { 
            await page.goto('test.com/second', { waituntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'] });
        } catch(e) {
            logIn()
        } 

        // more stuff not relevant here
    }    

})();


function logIn(){
                await page.goto('test.com', { waituntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'] });
                await page.evaluate((user, pass) => {
                    document.querySelector('#user').setAttribute('value', user);
                }, user, pass)
                await page.click('button[type=submit].btn-primary');
}
```

However, this won't work because await only works inside an aysnc. Now one idea is to place await in front of the logIn call like this:

```
await logIn()
```

But here is the thing. Inside that `logIn` function, I purposely use await 3 times because I need one statement to be resolved before the next.

How can I achieve this? Use async/await and use my logIn function?

Comment: did you try `async function logIn(){ ...` ?

Comment: You also always need .catch for async IIFE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `logIn` function as an async function too:

```
async function logIn() {...}
```

then, when you call it, `await` for it:

```
await logIn();
```

like so:

```
async function logIn() {
  await page.goto('test.com', {
    waituntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0']
  });
  await page.evaluate((user, pass) => {
    document.querySelector('#user').setAttribute('value', user);
  }, user, pass)
  await page.click('button[type=submit].btn-primary');
}

(async() => {
  await logIn();

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
      await page.goto('test.com/second', {
        waituntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0']
      });
    } catch (e) {
      logIn()
    }

    // more stuff not relevant here
  }
})();
```

[**More on async functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: `await` will need to be in the `catch` block, too

Answer (score 0):

The solution above also means that the function that calls login will also need to be async, as well as the function that calls that function, etc.  all the way to the top of your code base.

Essentially, using async anywhere means that all of your functions must be async and all of your functions must be called with await.

I wish we could just wrap the execution operator with await/async so that we wouldn't have to spread it throughout our entire applications.

I have found no solution that doesn't involve making all functions async and calling them with await.